# Microsoft Access 2010 Managed Code Add-In – Application Hangs

Tags: visual-studio, ms-access, add-in

I know I've had this before but I can't remember how to get around it.

I built a managed code add-in that works fine apart from one thing.  When I try to close the Access application the application window still persists unless I end task it.  When I'm debugging the add-in using Visual Studio 2010 it closes fine when I stop debugging.

I am setting all variables to nothing as part of the on disconnect event.

```
Public Sub OnDisconnection(ByVal RemoveMode As Extensibility.ext_DisconnectMode, ByRef custom As System.Array) Implements Extensibility.IDTExtensibility2.OnDisconnection
    'On Error Resume Next
    If Not MenuCommandControls Is Nothing Then MenuCommandControls.Delete()
    If Not MenuCommandDimensionVariable Is Nothing Then MenuCommandDimensionVariable.Delete()
    If Not MenuCommandFields Is Nothing Then MenuCommandFields.Delete()
    If Not MenuCommandForms Is Nothing Then MenuCommandForms.Delete()
    If Not MenuCommandParseSQL Is Nothing Then MenuCommandParseSQL.Delete()
    If Not MenuCommandQueries Is Nothing Then MenuCommandQueries.Delete()
    If Not MenuCommandReports Is Nothing Then MenuCommandReports.Delete()
    If Not MenuCommandTables Is Nothing Then MenuCommandTables.Delete()
    If Not MenuCommandVariables Is Nothing Then MenuCommandVariables.Delete()
    If Not searchForm Is Nothing Then searchForm.Close() : searchForm = Nothing
    If Not ObjectSetting Is Nothing Then ObjectSetting = Nothing
    If Not AccessInst Is Nothing Then AccessInst = Nothing
    If Not addInInstance Is Nothing Then addInInstance = Nothing
    'If Not FormParseSQL Is Nothing Then FormParseSQL = Nothing
    applicationObject.Quit(Access.AcQuitOption.acQuitPrompt)
    If Not applicationObject Is Nothing Then applicationObject = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

add x as optional integer to the subroutine

Create a Quit app button and 
setting x=1
call your subroutine, and pass the Optional x value to it.
putting the application.quit commmand

at bottom of subroutine, if x=1 then application.quit.

call ONdisconnect subroutine thru the quit app button.

disable all other ways to exit your application.

easy, simple and functional.

this way the Ondisconnect will work when a disconnect occurs or your closing the application.